# GET requests are not working on live server Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination, get

I have been working on a Laravel project, Everything worked fine on the local server, So i uploaded the project to a shared hosting so that I can show it to the client, Now all of the sudden none of the GET requests are working, everything works fine like, i can create new accounts, sign in etc, but all the functionalities that are depending on GET request are not working now, this even includes Pagination or Ajax requests, for pagination it show the pagination links, but for every page number it will only show the results of 1st page and for Ajax requests i am getting Status code 200 but it is not giving me any kind of response.

here is simple example of pagination

```
$items=Item::limit(12)->paginate(12);
$categories = DB::table('item_categories')->get();
return view('item_search', compact('items','categories'));
```

And an example of Ajax

REQUEST

```
var dataString= "id="+id;
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:"get_faq",
            data:dataString,
            success:function(data){
               document.getElementById("viewFaqMessage").innerHTML=data.answer;
               $('#viewFaqModal').modal('show');
            }
     })
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function get_faq(Request $request)
    {
        $data=Faq::where('id',$request->id)->first();
        return response()->json([
            'id'=> $data->id,
            'number'=>$data->number,
            'question' => $data->question,
            'answer' => $data->answer
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: `$items=Item::limit(12)->paginate(12);` You're only ever going to get the first 12 items. Paginate will handle the limit for you, so remove the `limit` clause.

Comment: `$data=Faq::where('id',$request->id)->first();` Shouldn't this always return only 1 row?

Comment: You say you're getting a 200 on the ajax response, but not getting anything else? Open your Developer Console and check the Network tab when you make the request. Check the Response of the request to see what it contains

Comment: yeah, i already checked that it says "this request has not response data available"

Comment: @aynber this $item was only one of many other examples, it still does not work after removing limit

Comment: @aynber and for Faq it supposed to return only 1 that is why i have put first(), it is not related to pagination

Comment: since it works in your local and not working on the deployment my hunch is the problem could be in this line `url:"get_faq",` check your ajax request's url and prefix your url like this `url:"/get_faq",` or use full url